# Problems with WCF Webservice and SSL

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl

I've read lots of threads the last hours but I did not find a solution which is working for me :-(

So as already multiple other users I have problems calling a SVC-Webservice via SSL from my Windows Phone 7 application. On localhost it works fine. I've deployed the Webservice within my Webapplication. The service "MyService.svc" is in the root of the webapplication. On IIS I've only added HTTPS (from Startcom, using default Port 443) for this IP and made SSL required. I could open my web application and I could open the Webservice using any browser at http://mydomain.com/MyService.svc, from both server and local development machine. The page says I could call svcutil.exe https://mydomain.com/MyService.svc?wsdl. When I click on the link the data is display correct.

Now when I try to access it via WP7 app I always get the following error:
*"There was no endpoint listening at https://mydomain.com/MyService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."*
And inner details say: *"The remote server returned an error: NotFound."*
Here is the important part of my web.config. I don't know whether this is all required, as said I've copied it from multiple threads but at least in IE it works fine:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1073741824" />
                <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                    <defaultPorts>
                        <add scheme="https" port="443" />
                    </defaultPorts>
                </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="MyNamespace.MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding"
                      contract="MyNamespace.IMyService">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="HttpsBinding">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <!-- <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /> -->
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It's odd that you can use a browser fine and not WP7. Perhaps (I'm guessing) check if you have installed your cert properly **including any intermediate certificates**. I'm not well versed on WP7 but do know that browsers perform some "auto discovery" of certificate chains (to a trusted `Root Cert`). So I'm **guessing** that WP may not have this capability (auto-discover) just like in server to server communications (and therefore fails to connect properly over https - re: untrusted root). Check on your SSL [here](http://www.digicert.com/help/)

Comment: Sorry I"m not answering so have to use comments...[WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.100).aspx) may help you get even more detail.

Comment: Are you using self signed certificate on your IIS or is it an certificate issued by a trusted authority? If its self signed then your would need to to add the certficate on the trusted ppl store on your WP7.